# Two figures, one is not a manifold, but the other is a manifold, but they look both as suffering from the same deficiencies for not being a manifold

Tags: general-topology, analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

I am looking [video lectures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uGEV0Wk0eIk) of F. Schuller about space-time geometry, in particular about manifolds. In it, right at the beginning after introducing manifolds he [gives a non-example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uGEV0Wk0eIk#t=14m0s), i.e. he says that

[image]

is not a manifold as the point where both circles meet (which I made thicker to show it), it is not possible to assign a dimension in concordence with the other points. Intuitively, if I think of this set equipped with the subspace topology derived from the standard topology on $\mathbb R^2$ I am somehow convinced that every open neighbourhood around the problematic point does not resemble an open subset of $\mathbb R$ (despite I do not see how to prove this more formally). Then later in the lecture, after introducing fibres, he gives the [following example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uGEV0Wk0eIk#t=31m33s)

[image]

supposing this is a manifold (the circles "shrink down" to a single point, which I made thicker to highlight it, and then "expand" in lines again), indeed by definition of fibres the entire figure is what he called the total space, which by definition is a manifold.

But comparing this with the non-example, this has in some sense analog deficiencies, the line and the circle (or the vertical lines) meet in a single point, which could be seen as problematic with the same arguments as for the non-example (similar I guess the intersection of two distinct lines is not a manifold, as the intersection point is also problematic).

> So, why is the second figure a manifold, but the first not, if the second also has these problematic points where the parts meet at single points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in this case the total space is not a manifold, even though the base space and the fibres over any point are.

Comment: So this seems to be an error in the lectures?

Comment: @Stefan Wait, I'm watching it. But I assume he calls it a "manifold bundle"? That would not mean that the total space is a manifold, but only that every fibre is a manifold (similarly, a vector bundle is a fibre bundle where all fibres are vector spaces).

Comment: Okay, I wait...

Comment: @Stefan I've watched for a while but I've not seen him give a name to that object... Anyway rest assured that your intuition is correct, and that the total space in this case is not a manifold. It seems a nice series of lectures by the way :)

Comment: Yes, he is doing a good job, right level of rigor and intuition.